# Is it possible to update registered singleton using unity container, c#?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm using [unity container](http://unitycontainer.org/articles/introduction.html) to implement a singleton design.

This is my code:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
   public MyObj obj {get;private set;}
}
```

creating the singleton :

```
container.RegistryInstance(new ExampleClass());
```

get the singleton:

```
container.Resolve<ExampleClass>();
```

I'd like to update the obj object and to keep on the singleton object,

**How can I update the singleton object?**

I tried like this(this is not right):

```
container.Resolve<ExampleClass>(new new ExampleClass());
```